# How to create a real-time plot with mpld3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, matplotlib, websocket, mpld3

Is there a way to add a new data point and remove an old one (push, shift principle) with mpld3 on the frontend side?
I would like to make a real-time plot using mpld3.
Initializing the plot once and updating it with websockets for example...
The only way I could think of so far is updating the data directly in javascript after initialization using the underlying d3 library like in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070) example .

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do this using `D3.JS` on the client side.

If you really hate writing JS code and are OK with having to refresh the page to update, you can do this by providing the image via a hook on your backend which rewrites and sends a fresh `matplotlib` figure every time a request is made. This is a Bad Idea though, for a variety of reasons.

I'm not aware of any capacity in which `mpld3` in and of itself is helpful here, sorry.